# Mysql datatype SET with rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So for some reason, our database guy decided to use the mysql datatype set.
I'm trying to make it work with rails.
Here is our column:

```
actions => set('spoke_to','left_voicemail','emailed')
```

To make it work I have the following code which i'm sure could be far better:

```
def actions=(type)
    write_attribute(:actions, pack(type))
  end

  def actions
      read_attribute(:actions).split(",") unless read_attribute(:actions).nil?
  end

  private


  def pack(type)
    acs = self.actions
    if acs.present? && acs.include?(type)
     acs.delete(type)
     delete_actions(acs)
    else
      write_actions(acs, type)
    end
  end

  def delete_actions(acs)
    if acs.empty?
      write_attribute(:actions, nil)
    else
      write_attribute(:actions, acs)
    end
  end

  def write_actions(acs, type)
    debugger
    if acs.present?
      write_attribute(:actions, acs.push(type).join(","))
    else
      write_attribute(:actions, type)
    end
  end
```

However, setting the action(s) works just like fine, but when I try to unset one I have the following weird query being generated:

```
(72.5ms)  BEGIN
(73.6ms)  UPDATE `service_requests` SET `actions` = '---\n- spoke_to\n- left_voicemail\n' WHERE `service_requests`.`nid` = 69524843
(78.2ms)  COMMIT
```

And I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error was occurring in this line `write_attribute(:actions, acs)` in the delete method.
It's because write_attribute was trying to write yaml in the DB(I think) so I had to this:

```
def delete_actions(acs)
    if acs.empty?
      write_attribute(:actions, nil)
    else
      write_attribute(:actions, acs.join(','))
    end
end
```

I feel a bit stupid not thinking about it right away but, eh here goes the life...